# Issue decrypting with CommonCrypto in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cryptography, commoncrypto

I am working in a `Swift-only` crypt/decrypt `Extension` for `String` and `NSData`, and the crypt part is working based in the answer provided by @Zaph in the linked question: [Issue using CCCrypt (CommonCrypt) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754147/issue-using-cccrypt-commoncrypt-in-swift)

The crypt output was tested using the good old NSData+AESCrypt.m Category in Objective-C

I have been working in the decrypt part with an issue: The code compiles and runs fine, but the result is not the expected text originally encrypted.

```
extension NSData {
    func AES256EncryptDataWithKey(key: String) -> NSData {
        let keyData: NSData! = (key as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let keyBytes         = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)
        let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)
        let dataLength    = UInt(self.length)
        let dataBytes     = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(self.bytes)
        let bufferData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        var bufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferData.mutableBytes)
        let bufferLength  = size_t(bufferData.length)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        var numBytesEncrypted: UInt = 0
        var cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes, keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes, dataLength,
            bufferPointer, bufferLength,
            &numBytesEncrypted)
        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            bufferData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted) // Requiered to adjust buffer size
            return bufferData as NSData
        } else {
            println("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
            return NSData()
        }
    }

    func AES256DecryptDataWithKey(key: String) -> NSData {
        let keyData: NSData! = (key as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let keyBytes         = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)
        let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)
        let dataLength    = UInt(self.length)
        let dataBytes     = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(self.bytes)
        let string = self.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        let bufferData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        var bufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferData.mutableBytes)
        let bufferLength  = size_t(bufferData.length)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        var numBytesDecrypted: UInt = 0
        var cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes, keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes, dataLength,
            bufferPointer, bufferLength,
            &numBytesDecrypted)            
        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            bufferData.length = Int(numBytesDecrypted) // Requiered to adjust buffer size
            return bufferData as NSData
        } else {
            println("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
            return NSData()
        }
    }
}

extension String {        
    func AES256EncryptStringWithKey(key: String) -> String {
        let data = (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let encryptedData = data.AES256EncryptDataWithKey(key)
        // Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
        let base64cryptString = encryptedData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        return base64cryptString
    }

    func AES256DecryptStringWithKey(key: String) -> String {
        let data: NSData! = (self as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let decryptedData = data.AES256DecryptDataWithKey(key)            
        // Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
        let base64decryptString = decryptedData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        return base64decryptString
    }
}
```

As you can see the `String.encryptStringWithKey()` calls the `NSData.encryptDataWithKey()`. so the Extensions work for both types `String` and `NSData`

```
    let string: String = "Don´t try to read this text. Top Secret Stuff"
    let key = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
    println("Original String  : \(string)");
    let encryptedString = string.AES256EncryptStringWithKey(key)
    println("Encrypted String : \(encryptedString)")        
    let decryptedString = encryptedString.AES256DecryptStringWithKey(key)
    println("Decrypted String: \(decryptedString)")
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can do a hex dump of the input and output on both and compare the difference. Hex dump: operation, algorithm, options, keyBytes, keyLength, dataBytes, dataLength. Somewhere there is a difference.

Comment: @eharo2 Can you post how you modified your code to get it working? Did you stick with CommonCrypto or switch to RNCryptor? I'm trying to use CommonCrypto in swift 3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that NSData+AESCrypt.m is using CBC mode (the default) with an iv of NULL. The code in the question is using ECB mode.

Best practice is to use CBC mode with a random iv. The iv is typically pre-pended to the encrypted data so the decryption can separate the iv and data prior to decryption.

Do not use NSData+AESCrypt.m, it has not been maintained, is a category on NSData, does not support ARC. Consider [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) for Objective-C, it is actively maintained.

This is the change I made in "NSData+AESCrypt.m", method `AES256EncryptWithKey:`  `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCOptionECBMode`. I added `kCCOptionECBMode`, that's all.

Here is the call I made:
    NSString *keyString = @"12345678901234567890123456789012";

```
NSString *message = @"Don´t try to read this text. Top Secret Stuff";
NSData   *data    = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *crypData = [data AES256EncryptWithKey:keyString];
NSLog(@"crypData: %@", crypData);
```

Output:

```
crypData: <118a32dc c23f7caa 883abc3c 1c7f0770 e200016b 2737acfa 17bb96fb a02b02a7 c147603b 06acd863 94bb8ff2 6cb14515>
```

Which is the same as from the above code (the same as the previous question):

```
cryptData = <118a32dc c23f7caa 883abc3c 1c7f0770 e200016b 2737acfa 17bb96fb a02b02a7 c147603b 06acd863 94bb8ff2 6cb14515>
```

It is just a matter of getting all of the inputs the same: operation, algorithm, options, keyBytes, keyLength, dataBytes, dataLength and iv if non ECB mode. `CCCrypt` is just a function call, that's all. Put in the same input, get the same output.

Put in `NSLog()` statements, preferably hex dumps for data and strings. Compare and fix as needed.

Believe it or not, this is the easy part of electronic security.

Comment: Hi @Zaph.  I have a NSData+AESCrypt.m version that uses ECB mode and a NULL iv. Given that the Swift code you provided to encrypt in the other related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754147/issue-using-cccrypt-commoncrypt-in-swift), I tested and was able to crypt with Swift and decrypt with Objective-C. Can you help me find what is missing in this NSData Swift Extension?... rods..

Comment: I ran the NSData+AESCrypt.m with ECB (modified the code) and got the same results at the code in this question. ECB mode does not use an iv. With an iv of NULL the first encrypted block is the same with CBC or ECB, it is the following of the blocks that are different.

Comment: Thx @Zaph for pointing me in the right direction...   This is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.0 AES128 Encryption and Decryption.

Should import the following header into Obj-c bridge header inorder to work

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>


static func AES128Encryption()
    {
        let keyString        = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
        let keyData: NSData! = (keyString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let keyBytes         = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(keyData.bytes)
        print("keyLength   = \(keyData.length), keyData   = \(keyData)")

        let message       = "Don´t try to read this text. Top Secret Stuff"
        let data: NSData! = (message as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let dataLength    = size_t(data.length)
        let dataBytes     = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(data.bytes)
        print("dataLength  = \(dataLength), data      = \(data)")

        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(cryptData!.mutableBytes)
        let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData!.length)

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCOptionECBMode)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes, keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes, dataLength,
            cryptPointer, cryptLength,
            &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
          //  let x: UInt = numBytesEncrypted
            cryptData!.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            print("cryptLength = \(numBytesEncrypted), cryptData = \(cryptData)")

            // Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
            let base64cryptString = cryptData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
            print("base64cryptString = \(base64cryptString)")

        } else {
            print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        }
    }

    static func AES128Decryption(data:NSData) //data = cryptData
    {
        let keyString        = "12345678901234567890123456789012"
        let keyData: NSData! = (keyString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let keyBytes         = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(keyData.bytes)
        print("keyLength   = \(keyData.length), keyData   = \(keyData)")

        //let message       = "Don´t try to read this text. Top Secret Stuff"
       // let data: NSData! = (message as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let dataLength    = size_t(data.length)
        let dataBytes     = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(data.bytes)
        print("dataLength  = \(dataLength), data      = \(data)")

        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(cryptData!.mutableBytes)
        let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData!.length)

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCOptionECBMode)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes, keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes, dataLength,
            cryptPointer, cryptLength,
            &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            //  let x: UInt = numBytesEncrypted
            cryptData!.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            print("DecryptcryptLength = \(numBytesEncrypted), Decrypt = \(cryptData)")

            // Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
            let base64cryptString = cryptData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
            print("base64DecryptString = \(base64cryptString)")
               print( "utf8 actual string = \(NSString(data: cryptData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))");
        } else {
            print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well the code does not work out of the box. You could mention what should be added to the Obj-c bridge in order to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @Krystian Thanks for the comment.. Updated the answer

Comment: @karthikPrabhu I followed your code snippet but at decryption I get utf8 actual string = nil. And the base64DecryptString is random string value!

Answer (score 0):

Swift4 AES128 Decryption and JWT

**Note:** If iv is used along with key while encrypting the plain text dont use it while decrypting , your issue will be resolved.
**key and iv** length is 16bit

Following code for decryption may help you:
Here the **encrypted string** used for decryption is **base64Encoded** and the decrypted string which we get is JWT(Json Web Token).

To Configure CommonCrypto refer link:
[How is CommonCrypto used in SWIFT3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260005/how-is-commoncrypto-used-in-swift3)

https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption
https://jwt.io/

import UIKit
import CommonCrypto

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    testAES()
}


func testAES()  {

    let testMessSr  = "74oIlwieBbxGvHjibQoSxWWAL0zNfy7yaQboYizPc+ouMsAkXbvMNb0RagXklA2zOlo29J7Zr7zFiOalBfKSvV3pzw7KWCtTMw16SNeOIRWYpSWNcNXxgoQR7Jy33s0JP8elQCo/6G+inivE2hm3kl7QTr/Jz5bx/ho0LmWrirn/L4WAJlDFHue23vjhrKGIfEvwIdWHPNh1qd+hCY4pQA==:NjkzQUU1MkM5RTZERjNFMA=="

    //Here I'm separating iv from base64encoded string as while decrypting theres no need of iv
    let splitStr = testMessSr.components(separatedBy: ":")

    print("base64EncodedString: \(splitStr[0])")
    print("iv: \(splitStr[1])")

    let base64EncodedString = splitStr[0]

    let message = Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedString ,options : Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    let key         = "EE99C7A159003D36"
    let ivString     = "693AE52C9E6DF3E0"   // 16 bytes for AES128

   // let messageData = message.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let keyData     = key.data(using: .utf8)!
    let ivData      = ivString.data(using: .utf8)!

    let decryptedData = message?.aesEncrypt( keyData:keyData, ivData:ivData, operation:kCCDecrypt)
    print("decryptedData: \(decryptedData)")
    let decryptedString = String(data: decryptedData as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print("decryptedString: \(decryptedString)") //JWT token

}
```

}

extension Data{

```
func aesEncrypt( keyData: Data, ivData: Data, operation: Int) -> Data {
    let dataLength = self.count
    let cryptLength  = size_t(dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    var cryptData = Data(count:cryptLength)

    let keyLength = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
    let options = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)


    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        self.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            ivData.withUnsafeBytes {ivBytes in
                keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                    CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation),
                            CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                            options,
                            keyBytes, keyLength,
                            ivBytes,
                            dataBytes, dataLength,
                            cryptBytes, cryptLength,
                            &numBytesEncrypted)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.removeSubrange(numBytesEncrypted..<cryptData.count)

    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }

    return cryptData;
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this.  I got some great help from this with the specific line of code: `let message = Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedString ,options : Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)`. 
This is a good write-up.  Thanks for sharing. Upvoted!