# DES/ECB/NoPadding in swift 3.1 using Common Crypto

Tags: ios, encryption, swift3, des, commoncrypto

I would like to encrypt and decrypt strings in my iOS app using DES (yes I know DES isn't safe anymore but the app receives and send messages to a BLE module that uses it).
I successfully created a bridging header for Common Crypto and I found this for encryption and adapted it for DES and swift 3 [Asynchronous encryption in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222642/asynchronous-encryption-in-swift/29230965#29230965):

```
func testCrypt(data:NSData, keyData:NSData, ivData:NSData, operation:CCOperation) -> NSData? {

    let keyBytes = keyData.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    print("keyLength   = \(keyData.length), keyData   = \(keyData)")

    let ivBytes = ivData.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    print("ivLength    = \(ivData.length), ivData    = \(ivData)")

    let dataLength = Int(data.length)

    let dataBytes = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    print("dataLength  = \(dataLength), data      = \(data)")

    let cryptData: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeDES)

    let cryptPointer = cryptData.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData.length)

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeDES)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmDES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                              algoritm,
                              options,
                              keyBytes, keyLength,
                              ivBytes,
                              dataBytes, dataLength,
                              cryptPointer, cryptLength,
                              &numBytesEncrypted)

    return cryptData;
}
```

Function call and parameters:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ivString = "Use a random iv!"
    let ivData = (ivString as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSData!

    let key = Data.init(bytes: [0x23, 0x12, 0x4d, 0x89, 0x88, 0x34, 0xCf, 0x50])
    let keyData = NSData.init(data: key)

    let message = "Don´t try to read this text. Top Secret Stuff"
    let data = (message as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSData!

    print("data: \(data)")
    if let encryptedData = testCrypt(data: data!, keyData:keyData, ivData: ivData!, operation:UInt32(kCCEncrypt)) {
        print("encryptedData: \(encryptedData)")
        if let decryptedData = testCrypt(data: encryptedData, keyData:keyData, ivData: ivData!, operation:UInt32(kCCDecrypt)) {
            let dec = Data.init(referencing: decryptedData)
            print("decryptedData: \(decryptedData))")
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result = <446f6ec2 b4742074 72792074 6f207265 61642074 68697320 74657874 2e20546f 70205365 63726574 20537475 6666>

encryptedData: <6081ada9 0487c0a5 35e542bd e9600861 4250a693 65573337 39df5525 66c40cd8 b358bf6a d9837f9c 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000>

decryptedData = <446f6ec2 b4742074 72792074 6f207265 61642074 68697320 74657874 2e20546f 70205365 63726574 e0456e88 3f896b9b 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000>

Why decryption returns a right result only in part?

Comment: Where does the code come from? What is your input data, expected output and actual output? What does "strange result" mean?

Comment: @MartinR sorry for the lac of details, I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like there's no NoPadding options available, in the end I just removed '+ kCCBlockSizeDES' from 'cryptData' initialization and added '0' characters to my string before encrypting it to reach a right size (for example a length multiple of 8) and then after decryption I just removed the zeros to get the original string.

Comment: Hi dude, Can you update the answer with any example(How you are passing arguments to CCCrypt method). It would be very grateful.