# Swift - Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<Any>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'

Tags: swift, pointers, encryption, types, commoncrypto

I am trying to use CommonCrypto (with the help of https://github.com/sergejp/CommonCrypto) for the first time with swift. Here is my code:

```
UnsafeRawPointer(ivData!.withUnsafeBytes
{(pointer) -> UnsafePointer<Any> in
    let ivBuffer = pointer
})
```

The error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer' to expected argument
>   type 'UnsafePointer<_>'

What does the `<_>` signify? What do I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: Its saying that you cannot convert the type UnsafePointer to a UnsafePointer with a type. I think you need to remove <Any>. Above that it is hard to know with out more code as context.

Comment: i get another error when I do this `Reference to generic type 'UnsafePointer' requires arguments in <...>` telling me to revert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `pointer` that it is complaining about.  You need to cast it.  Here's an example usage, part of creating an MD5 hash:

```
    var rawBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    let _ = data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
        CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), &rawBytes)
    }
```

Comment: great thanks that did it....are the `rawBytes` always able to be cast as `UInt8`? I am doing AES encryption

Comment: You can cast it to whatever you want.  To be clear, the reason that you have to cast it is because you are returning it, and `preBuffer` will be whatever type you are casting it to. Take a look at the Swift 3 answer using `Data` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680361/aes-encryption-in-swift, it might provide more insight into how to use it.

Comment: Side note: you should try to avoid using the force-unwrap operator `!` where you can, by using `if let` or `guard let` constructs.  Colloquially, `!` is known as the "crash operator"

Comment: yah im just figuring the optionals out...i have guard where i need it in most places except below i plan on putting that in

Comment: great link...i was looking for something like that for a while to base my encryption function on