# Swift 5 + kCCDecrypt (CommonCrypto): Failing to decrypt

Tags: aes, commoncrypto, swift5

Trying to write my own encrypt/decrypt functions in `Swift 5`, based on tons of other similar questions -- and failing miserably.

I'm using `CommonCrypto` + `CCCrypt` to encrypt/decrypt (AES, 256 key, random iv).

I'm favouring `NSData.bytes` over `withUnsafeBytes` (which is just [too confusing](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811) in `Swift 5`).

My `encrypt` function goes like this:

```swift
func encrypt(_ string: String) throws -> Data {
    guard let dataToEncrypt: Data = string.data(using: .utf8) else {
        throw AESError.stringToDataFailed
    }

    // Seems like the easiest way to avoid the `withUnsafeBytes` mess is to use NSData.bytes.
    let dataToEncryptNSData = NSData(data: dataToEncrypt)

    let bufferSize: Int = ivSize + dataToEncryptNSData.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
    defer { buffer.deallocate() }

    let status: Int32 = SecRandomCopyBytes(
        kSecRandomDefault,
        kCCBlockSizeAES128,
        buffer
    )
    guard status == 0 else {
        throw AESError.generateRandomIVFailed
    }

    var numberBytesEncrypted: Int = 0

    let cryptStatus: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt( // Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
        CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),                // op: CCOperation
        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),           // alg: CCAlgorithm
        options,                                // options: CCOptions
        key.bytes,                              // key: the "password"
        key.length,                             // keyLength: the "password" size
        buffer,                                 // iv: Initialization Vector
        dataToEncryptNSData.bytes,              // dataIn: Data to encrypt bytes
        dataToEncryptNSData.length,             // dataInLength: Data to encrypt size
        buffer + kCCBlockSizeAES128,            // dataOut: encrypted Data buffer
        bufferSize,                             // dataOutAvailable: encrypted Data buffer size
        &numberBytesEncrypted                   // dataOutMoved: the number of bytes written
    )

    guard cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
        throw AESError.encryptDataFailed
    }

    return Data(bytes: buffer, count: numberBytesEncrypted + ivSize)
}
```

The `decrypt` function:

```
func decrypt(_ data: Data) throws -> String {

    // Seems like the easiest way to avoid the `withUnsafeBytes` mess is to use NSData.bytes.
    let dataToDecryptNSData = NSData(data: data)

    let bufferSize: Int = dataToDecryptNSData.length - ivSize
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
    defer { buffer.deallocate() }

    var numberBytesDecrypted: Int = 0

    let cryptStatus: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(         // Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
        CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),                        // op: CCOperation
        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),                // alg: CCAlgorithm
        options,                                        // options: CCOptions
        key.bytes,                                      // key: the "password"
        key.length,                                     // keyLength: the "password" size
        dataToDecryptNSData.bytes,                      // iv: Initialization Vector
        dataToDecryptNSData.bytes + kCCBlockSizeAES128, // dataIn: Data to decrypt bytes
        bufferSize,                                     // dataInLength: Data to decrypt size
        buffer,                                         // dataOut: decrypted Data buffer
        bufferSize,                                     // dataOutAvailable: decrypted Data buffer size
        &numberBytesDecrypted                           // dataOutMoved: the number of bytes written
    )

    guard cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
        throw AESError.decryptDataFailed
    }

    let decryptedData = Data(bytes: buffer, count: numberBytesDecrypted)

    guard let decryptedString = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw AESError.dataToStringFailed
    }

    return decryptedString
}
```

Those were based on [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681510/584548) from the user "@zaph".

Although `encrypt` seems to be working, `decrypt` fails.

This line specifically:

```swift
guard let decryptedString = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) else {
    throw AESError.dataToStringFailed
}
```

So of course I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what it is. Could you?

Here is the pastebin with the entire code, which you could copy/paste in a Playground and hit play. `Swift 5` is required: https://pastebin.com/raw/h6gacaHX

> **Update**
>   I'm now following @OOper's suggested approach. The final code can be seen here:
>   https://github.com/backslash-f/aescryptable

Comment: `NSData.bytes` may not give you what you expect. If you want to write code which works steady in Swift, never use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, using `Data.withUnsafeBytes` is sort of a mess in Swift 5, though `NSData.bytes` cannot be *the easiest way*, as using it would sometimes seemingly work, and sometimes not.

You need to be accustomed work with `Data.withUnsafeBytes` if you want to write an always-works code in Swift with `Data`.

```
struct AES {
    private let key: Data //<- Use `Data` instead of `NSData`

    private let ivSize: Int                     = kCCBlockSizeAES128
    private let options: CCOptions              = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    init(keyString: String) throws {
        guard keyString.count == kCCKeySizeAES256 else {
            throw AESError.invalidKeySize
        }
        guard let keyData: Data = keyString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            throw AESError.stringToDataFailed
        }
        self.key = keyData
    }
}

extension AES: Cryptable {

    func encrypt(_ string: String) throws -> Data {
        guard let dataToEncrypt: Data = string.data(using: .utf8) else {
            throw AESError.stringToDataFailed
        }

        let bufferSize: Int = ivSize + dataToEncrypt.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128
        var buffer = Data(count: bufferSize)

        let status: Int32 = buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes {bytes in
            SecRandomCopyBytes(
                kSecRandomDefault,
                kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                bytes.baseAddress!
            )
        }
        guard status == 0 else {
            throw AESError.generateRandomIVFailed
        }

        var numberBytesEncrypted: Int = 0

        let cryptStatus: CCCryptorStatus = key.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
            dataToEncrypt.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
                buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes {bufferBytes in
                    CCCrypt( // Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
                        CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),                // op: CCOperation
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),           // alg: CCAlgorithm
                        options,                                // options: CCOptions
                        keyBytes.baseAddress,                   // key: the "password"
                        key.count,                              // keyLength: the "password" size
                        bufferBytes.baseAddress,                // iv: Initialization Vector
                        dataBytes.baseAddress,                  // dataIn: Data to encrypt bytes
                        dataToEncrypt.count,                    // dataInLength: Data to encrypt size
                        bufferBytes.baseAddress! + kCCBlockSizeAES128, // dataOut: encrypted Data buffer
                        bufferSize,                             // dataOutAvailable: encrypted Data buffer size
                        &numberBytesEncrypted                   // dataOutMoved: the number of bytes written
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        guard cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
            throw AESError.encryptDataFailed
        }

        return buffer[..<(numberBytesEncrypted + ivSize)]
    }

    func decrypt(_ data: Data) throws -> String {

        let bufferSize: Int = data.count - ivSize
        var buffer = Data(count: bufferSize)

        var numberBytesDecrypted: Int = 0

        let cryptStatus: CCCryptorStatus = key.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
            data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
                buffer.withUnsafeMutableBytes {bufferBytes in
                    CCCrypt(         // Stateless, one-shot encrypt operation
                        CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),                        // op: CCOperation
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),                // alg: CCAlgorithm
                        options,                                        // options: CCOptions
                        keyBytes.baseAddress,                           // key: the "password"
                        key.count,                                      // keyLength: the "password" size
                        dataBytes.baseAddress,                          // iv: Initialization Vector
                        dataBytes.baseAddress! + kCCBlockSizeAES128,    // dataIn: Data to decrypt bytes
                        bufferSize,                                     // dataInLength: Data to decrypt size
                        bufferBytes.baseAddress,                        // dataOut: decrypted Data buffer
                        bufferSize,                                     // dataOutAvailable: decrypted Data buffer size
                        &numberBytesDecrypted                           // dataOutMoved: the number of bytes written
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        guard cryptStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
            throw AESError.decryptDataFailed
        }

        let decryptedData = buffer[..<numberBytesDecrypted]

        guard let decryptedString = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw AESError.dataToStringFailed
        }

        return decryptedString
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh boy... I was trying to avoid that and handling all these force unwrapping thing. But perhaps I am over-engineering / over-complicating it. Would you have more info on why `NSData.bytes` works erratically?

Comment: @backslash-f, for example, the doc of `NSData.bytes` says _For an immutable data object, the returned pointer is valid until the data object is deallocated._ And in an optimized context, the extent of life time of `NSData` is hard to expect. Which may be deallocated just after the last usage. But in your case, what is critical in your code is this line: `let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)`, which allocates a heap which can hold multiple number (=`bufferSize`) of `NSData`.

Comment: I see. I missed that line from the docs. :/ Well, I'm accepting your answer. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Tried above code got 'dataToStringFailed' error for guard let decryptedString = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw AESError.dataToStringFailed
        }

Comment: @Vasu, I cannot reproduce the same issue. You should better start your own thread with enough info to reproduce the issue.