# Data encrypted by CryptoSwift is not same as Node.js

Tags: node.js, swift, encryption, cryptography, cryptoswift

I used CryptoSwift to encrypt some data, and then encrypted the same data using Node.js. But the results are not same. I asked the author, he said it's not a bug.

I don't know where I made a mistake. Here are pictures of how I used CryptoSwift and Node.js:

Cipher algorithm: aes-256-cfb

key: 32 bytes 1

iv: 16 bytes 0

CryptoSwift: develop-branch 0.1.1

Node.js: LTS 4.2.3

[Data encrypted by CryptoSwift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFWaT.png)

[Data encrypted by Node.js 4.2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwbhW.png)

Here is swift code:

```
    func testAES() {
    let key = [UInt8](count: 32, repeatedValue: 1)
    let iv = [UInt8](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
    print(key)
    print(iv)

    let aes256cfb = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CFB)

    let en1 = try! aes256cfb.encrypt([0x5, 0x77], padding: nil)
    print(en1.map({ i in String(format: "%2x", i)}))

    let en2 = try! aes256cfb.encrypt([0x5, 0x0, 0x3, 0x89, 0x20], padding: nil)
    print(en2.map({ i in String(format: "%2x", i)}))
}

CryptoSwift: 
["77", "ef"]
["77", "98", "c9", "2c", "45"]

Node.js: 
<Buffer 77 ef>
<Buffer cf a5 66 8a 3e>
```

You can see, the first two bytes are same, but the rest are not. Why? Is my code writing wrong? I don't know much about crypto, please tell me the reason. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do not use CryptoSwift if you care about either performance or security. CryptoSwift is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto and not well vetted or certified.

Comment: Why are you using CFB mode, the general case is to use CBC mode.

Comment: Just test code, don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the data is a multiple of the block size (16-bytes) and the data size is known by both sides a-priori to meet the requirement padding is required. The generally used padding is PKCS#7 (PKCS#5 is essentially the same).

In the code no padding is specified so the balance of the block will be whatever junk is in the buffer or perhaps the algorithm *may* null pad it, it is always best not to rely on non-standard defaults.

See the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25755864/451475) for an example of using Common Crypto.

But the best thing to do is use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) for your encryption, it is available for several languages and platforms. It also handles all the bits that make encryption secure. It is well vetted and being actively developed.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try to fix it. :)

Comment: Here is new question: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/175, could you please tell me why data not same?

Comment: I'm using RNCryptor, and seem to be getting terribly slow decryption speeds, such as 5-10 seconds to decrypt like 400 simple strings.

Comment: Swift or node.js? Swift used common crypto so would use hardware acceleration, nothing should be faster. But if you are using a password as opposed to a key you will be deriving a key for each encryption and that process takes about 100ms by design. If you do not need key derivation and/or authentication use Common Crypto directly. There are several Swift implementations available on SO.

Answer (score 1):

To answer that question.

Your NodeJS code encrypt [0x5, 0x77, 0x5, 0x0, 0x3, 0x89, 0x20], but your CryptoSwift code encrypt [0x5, 0x77] then [0x5, 0x0, 0x3, 0x89, 0x20]. This is why you get different results.

Comment: @Neko Wow, I did not look at the code well. You can't just concatenate encrypted bytes from separate encryptions. Perhaps full blocks in ECB but even that is broken thinking. Marcin: +1