# AES Decryption in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, openssl

I'm encrypting a file "info.plist" using openssl in mac.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in info.plist -out info.data -pass pass:myPass
```

How can I decrypt this info.data file in my iOS app?
I tried to use CryptoSwift pod but I can't figure out to make it work.

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Answer (score 1):

See the first answer for this question:[Issue using CCCrypt (CommonCrypt) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754147/issue-using-cccrypt-commoncrypt-in-swift)

It has an example for AES256 Decryption