# how to add triple des encryption decryption in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

i am very tensed last 2 days due to encryption / decryption in triple Des in swift i am follow below link but not its show error  where i get libraries of  CCAlgorithem and CCOptions  please check below image and please help me this

> Note: I'm New In Swift Xcode

how to add these library in my code i'm new in swift

```
import UIKit
import CryptoSwift


class CypherSwift: NSObject {


    func tripleDesEncrypt(pass: String) -> String{
        //help from this thread
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754147/issue-using-cccrypt-commoncrypt-in-swift

        let keyString        = "25d1d4cb0a08403e2acbcbe0"
        let keyData: NSData! = (keyString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!

        let message       = pass
        let data: NSData! = (message as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!

        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(data.length) + kCCBlockSize3DES)!

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                  algoritm,
                                  options,
                                  keyData.bytes, keyLength,
                                  nil,
                                  data.bytes, data.length,
                                  cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

            // Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
            var base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

            print("base64cryptString = \(base64cryptString)")
            base64cryptString = base64cryptString + "\n"
            return encodeString(base64cryptString)

        } else {
            print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        }
        return ""
    }

    func encodeString(str: String) -> String{
        let customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"==\n").invertedSet
        let escapedString = str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(customAllowedSet)
        print("escapedString: \(escapedString)")
        return escapedString!

    }

}
```

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1q82.png)

[tiple des link 1](https://github.com/phynet/Swift-CypherTripleDesEncrypt)

[triple des link 2](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift)

Comment: Please add your code in your question, instead of a link to a picture.

Comment: Why you don't use https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: @balanced i used but there is no encrypt decrypt function in triple des

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no pre-defined Swift module for CommonCrypto, which means that you'll either have to create one yourself in a `module.modulemap` file, or import it in your bridging header. If you're making an app and not a framework, the latter is the easiest: just create a bridging header (if you don't have one, just add an Objective-C source file to the project and it'll offer to create one automatically; you can delete the Objective-C source file afterwards). Next, add this to the bridging header:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

Note that if you're making a framework, the bridging header won't work and you'll have to make a modulemap instead (let me know if this is the case, and I'll edit something into the answer).

Anyway, the above will get rid of all the errors about `kCC` things not being found. Now that that's done, there are still a few things in the code that need fixing.

First of all, get rid of the unnecessary use of NS classes. Change:

```
let keyData: NSData! = (keyString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
```

to:

```
let keyData = keyString.data(using: .utf8)!
```

The `!` is acceptable in this case, since we know what `keyString` is and we know that it's definitely always convertible to UTF-8.

Now, do the same thing for `data`. Unfortunately in this case, `message` depends on user input, so we shouldn't use `!`—if the message turns out not to be convertible to UTF-8, `!` will cause your app to crash, which usually isn't what you want. It's better to use `guard let` and then bail if the conversion fails, either by making your function's return value optional and returning `nil` or adding `throws` to your function's return value and throwing an error:

```
guard let data = message.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return nil
    OR:
    throw CocoaError(.fileReadInapplicableStringEncoding) // or some custom error
}
```

The next issue is the use of `bytes` on your `Data` object. In Swift, this is not allowed, because it's unsafe; if the `Data` is deallocated before you're done with `bytes`, you'll crash or run into other weird behavior. Instead, you should use `withUnsafeBytes`, and do the work requiring the bytes inside a closure. This is safer, since the `Data` is guaranteed to be valid at least until the closure returns. Since we have three separate `Data`s that we need the bytes of, this is kind of unwieldy with a triple-nested closure, but we can do it:

```
let cryptStatus = keyData.withUnsafeBytes { (keyBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    data.withUnsafeBytes { (dataBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
        cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (cryptBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
            CCCrypt(operation,
                    algoritm,
                    options,
                    keyBytes,
                    keyLength,
                    nil,
                    dataBytes,
                    data.count,
                    cryptBytes,
                    cryptData.count,
                    &numBytesEncrypted)
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you've just got some more Objective-C-isms to make properly Swifty, and your encrypt function should be done:

```
cryptData.count = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

// Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
var base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

The only problem I see in the encode function is a few Objective-C-isms that you should modernize:

```
let customAllowedSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "==\n").inverted
let escapedString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: customAllowedSet)
```

There's also the calling convention of your encode function; `func encodeString(str: String)` means you'll have to call it like `return encodeString(str: base64cryptString)` with the label present. If you want to call it without the label, you can change the signature to `func encodeString(_ str: String)`.

Comment: how to #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>  add this file

Comment: Thanks for your response . i am working on it can you please  answer my above question

Comment: @john As I said in the answer, if you add an Objective-C source file to your project, Xcode will offer to automatically create a bridging header for you. You can then delete the Objective-C source file. Add the `#import` line to the bridging header file that Xcode makes.